# Keystroke to set focus on a particular browser - for Linux

Tags: linux, keyboard-shortcuts, browser, focus

I am doing web development, and I found that I always lose focus on the browser that I am doing development on.

I always open other browser windows at the same time for searching, writing, etc. So there are a lot of applications running at the same time.

Each time I wish to return to test my webpage on the development browser, I have used a lot to time for searching that particular browser.

What I want to do is press a short key --> automatically focus on the particular browser, and maybe do a refresh if it is possible.

How do I do that on a Linux machine?

Comment: Not an answer, but a suggestion : You could use the Linux Workspaces to put the important browser windows in another workspace, so you could switch to them at the click of the mouse. See for example this article : [Add, Switch, And Change Workspace In Ubuntu Linux](http://www.addictivetips.com/ubuntu-linux-tips/add-switch-and-change-workspace-in-ubuntu-linux/). ![enter image description here](http://i.stack.imgur.com/BR5wv.png)

Comment: Do you have any web development experience? Will you find difficulty on searching your web development browser?

Comment: What I normally do for web development is use one browser session with tabs, and I always keep the tabs in the same order. If I use virtual machines to simulate the network, this serves to further separate the development and test environments. In Firefox you can also use [these keyboard shortcuts](http://support.mozilla.com/en-US/kb/Keyboard%20shortcuts#w_windows-tabs) for positioning between tabs, and especially the wonderful [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/).

Comment: I think this is actually the right answer. You create virtual Desktops  and put the Browsers on different virtual Desktops. The default shortcuts to go to a desktop are STRG+F1 to STRG+F12 (On KDE at least). This way you could switch between browsers by putting them on different desktops. After the switch the top window on that desktop should automagically be activated.

Comment: Whether or not this can be easily done depends mainly on the **[Window Manager](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_window_manager)** your system is using. Your question does not include this information. You did not even mention the distribution you are using.

Answer (score 1):

Open *Automator* and select to create a *Service* that receives *no input* in *any application*. Double-click the *Launch Application* action and select your browser. Save as e.g. *Go To Safari*. This will work with any web browser. *Launch Application* will bring it to the front if it's already running.

[image]

---

If you want to also reload the frontmost tab, you need to use AppleScript in supported browsers. For Safari, replace *Launch Application* with *Run AppleScript*, and paste the following script code:

```
tell application "Safari"
    activate
    do JavaScript "window.location.reload();" in first document
end tell
```

This will focus Safari and reload the frontmost document.

---

To focus and reload Google Chrome, use the following AppleScript instead:

```
tell application "Google Chrome"
    activate
    reload active tab of first window
end tell
```

---

Firefox and Camino don't seem to have scripting capabilities to do this. But you can always fall back to OS X's accessibility API, e.g.

```
tell application "Safari" to activate
tell application "System Events" to keystroke "r" using command down
```

This will simply simulate a `Cmd-R` key press in the program you switched to in the first line.

---

If you want to select a particular *window* of your web browser, you can use something like the following, again using UI scripting:

```
tell application "Safari" to activate
tell application "System Events"
    tell application process "Safari"
        click menu item "Super User" of menu of menu bar item "Window" of menu bar 1
    end tell
end tell
```

This will programmatically click the menu item corresponding to a specific window in the standard *Window* menu in most applications.

---

To assign a keyboard shortcut, go to *System Preferences » Keyboard » Keyboard Shortcuts » Services*, select the *Go To Safari* service you just created, and assign a keyboard shortcut there.

Repeat for all browsers you want to do this in.

[image]

Comment: Do you have alternative solution for Linux env?

Comment: @KitHo Your question didn't indicate for what OS you needed a solution. The scripting capabilities and their integration in the UI are one of the reasons I prefer OS X — I don't know how you'd do this on Linux.